# GCP : gsutil -m cp -rn /Downloads gs://my-bucket - How to skip files already copied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3duHw.png)

When I resume copying files its works on two processes 1) Skipping Copied files and 2) Copying files.
Because of this it's taking a long time.
Is there any method to skip this already copied files during the process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be achieved by using the the `gsutil rsync` command.

The `gsutil rsync` command synchronises the contents of the source directory and the destination directory by copying only the missing files. It's therefore much more efficient than the standard vanilla `cp` command. 
However, if you're using the `-n` switch with the `cp` command, this forces the cp command to skip the files already copied. So whether or not using `gsutil rsync` is faster than `gsutil cp -n` is open to debate, and maybe depends on different scenarios.

To use gsutil rsync you can run something like this (the -r flag makes the command recursive):

```
gustil rsync -r source gs://mybucket/
```

For more detailed on the `gsutil rsync` command, please take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync).

I understand you have some concerns about the time it take for both commands to calculate which files need to be copied. As both the `gsutil cp -n`  and `gsutil rsync` commands both need to make a comparison between the source and destination directories, there is always going to be a certain amount of overhead/delay on top of the the copying process, especially with very large collections.

If you want to cut out this part of the process altogether, and you only want to copy files less than a certain age, you could specify this at source and use a standard gsutil copy command to see if that is faster. However, doing so would remove some of the benefits of `gsutil cp -n`  and `gsutil rsync` as there would no longer be a direct comparison between the source and destination directories.

For example, you could generate a variable at the source of files which have been modified recently, for example, within the last day. You could then use a standard `gsutil cp` command to only copy these files.

For example, to create a variable containing a list of files modified within the last day:

```
modified="$(find . -mtime -1)"
```

Then use the variable as the target for the copy command.

```
gsutil -m cp $modified gs://publicobject/
```

You need to work out whether or not this would work for your use case, as although there is chance it may be faster, some of the advantages of the other two methods are lost (automatic syncing of directories).

Comment: Now i am using, gsutil -m rsync -rn source gs://mybucket/.  It is taking too much time. And it is showing:  Building synchronization state...
At destination listing 10000...
At destination listing 20000...
At destination listing 30000...
At destination listing 40000...
At destination listing 50000...
At destination listing 60000...                                             Now what to do. Because i have to copy huge amount of data. And for this sometime i have pause copying files. Please help me.